Output in any other directory other than the dist folder
Trying out rsbuild and I have run into an interesting problem. What is the config that will let rsbuild output into an existing directory e.g. ./public
I want the assets to be nested under the public folder but every config I have made for the outpath deletes everything in that folder.

You should use the cleanDistPath configuration. Its default value is auto. You can set it to false:
// rsbuild.config.ts
export default {
  output: {
    cleanDistPath: true,
  },
};

